# doesn't work dataTables in playframework2.6.3

Tags: playframework, datatables-1.10

I use playframework2.6.3 and want to use dataTables (jquery-2.2.4, DataTables-1.10.15 ). But it doesn't work. I see simple html.

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>table</title>

    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="@routes.Assets.versioned("images/favicon.png")">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.versioned("stylesheets/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css")">
    <script src="@routes.Assets.versioned("javascripts/jquery-2.2.4.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@routes.Assets.versioned("javascripts/jquery.dataTables.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Column 1</th>
                <th>Column 2</th>
                <th>Column 3</th>
                <th>Column 4</th>
                <th>Column 5</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Column 1</th>
                <th>Column 2</th>
                <th>Column 3</th>
                <th>Column 4</th>
                <th>Column 5</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</body>
```

[image]

my dependencies do not work. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changed

> play.filters.headers.contentSecurityPolicy="default-src 'self'"

to for example

> contentSecurityPolicy = "default-src *; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; img-src * data: 'unsafe-inline'; connect-src * 'unsafe-inline'; frame-src *;"